# Package classicthesis and tikz figure numbering in marginpar

Tags: tikz-pgf, classicthesis, marginpar

I'm using the `classicthesis` package and I created some `tikz` pictures in the margin using `\marginpar`. Unfortunately the numbering of the figures is not correct. When I comment out the `classicthesis` package the numbering is correct. I created a MWE to show my problem

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman,main=UKenglish}{babel}   % change thi
\usepackage{babel}                  
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\marginpar{
   \begin{tikzpicture} 
     \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,2);
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \captionof{figure}{lalalallalalalal .}
 \label{fig1}
}
see fig \ref{fig1} and fig \ref{fig2}

\marginpar{
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \captionsetup{type=figure}
  \caption{lalalallalalalal .}
  \label{fig2}
}
\end{document}
```

And I get:
[image: Wrong figure numbers]

I'm using TeX Live 2015 on a Mac! Has somebody any idea how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to demonstrate that '\captionsetup' and '\captionof' doesnt make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `marginnote` package and its eponymous command `\marginnote`.

Answer (score 2):

Each marginpar is set twice to allow for possibly different settings in left and right margin. But you could reset the counter so it does not jump by two each time:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman,main=UKenglish}{babel}   % change thi
\usepackage{babel}                  
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{zzz}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{zzz}{\value{figure}}%
\marginpar{\setcounter{figure}{\value{zzz}}%
   \begin{tikzpicture} 
     \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,2);
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \captionof{figure}{lalalallalalalal .}
 \label{fig1}
}
see fig \ref{fig1} and fig \ref{fig2}

\setcounter{zzz}{\value{figure}}%
\marginpar{\setcounter{figure}{\value{zzz}}%
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \captionsetup{type=figure}
  \caption{lalalallalalalal .}
  \label{fig2}
}
\end{document}
```